# SPOF-less distributed file system?

Tags: filesystems

I’m looking for a free software, distributed, fault tolerant (ideally without Single Points of failure), mature, POSIX compliant file system (such a long requirements list, I know).

There are not so many projects with those features; this is my candidates list and I hope I didn’t miss anyone from it:

- Lustre;
- MooseFS;
- Tahoe-LAFS;
- XtreemFS.

I’m a beginner on this field and the "no [SPOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure)" requirement (or good solutions to avoid them) is essential.

Do you have any experience to share? Thanks.

Comment: I believe [Ceph](http://ceph.com/) is also shared-nothing, fully redundant. They have a POSIX-compliant filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

MooseFS (v. >= 2.0) in Pro version has no SPOF. It is a fully POSIX-compliant distributed filesystem. It is mature and actively developed.